# iOS: Symbolicate unarchieved crash report

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I've received a crash report from itunesconnect review team. I had uploaded this binary using Application Loader tool not by archiving and submitting it using xcode archive tool. Apple documentation describing how to symbolicate crash reports which have their associated binary files and .dSYM files automatically archived by the Archive tool.

How to tell xcode to symbolicate my crash report using unarchived binary and .dSYM that I have on my filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://sourceforge.net/p/umsservices/wiki/Home/

it would do the job for you